# need the sql query output like this

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query

```
SELECT 
  F.intfloorno,
  FL.nvrflatname 
FROM tbl_floormaster F 
INNER JOIN tbl_flatmaster FL ON FL.intfloorid=F.intfloorid 
WHERE intblockid=1 
ORDER BY intfloorno DESC
```

this is the output:

```
floorno        flat       
2          FlatB1
2          FlatB2
1          FlatA1
1          FlatA2
```

but i need it like this:

```
floorno  flat        dummycolum
1       FlatA1         FlatA2
2       FlatB2         FlatB2
```

Comment: what DB are you using (Oracle, SQL Server...) ?

Comment: Your example is not clear. First: do you only have two flats per floor or more? Second: On floorno = 2, flat column should be FlatB1, correct?

Comment: Are you trying to control the presentational output of this data for this query, or transpose the table results? If it's a presentation issue, remember that rendering the output is not the same as querying the relational table structure, as rsj mentions below.

Comment: in first floor i am having two flats,2 floor i am having two flats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT F.intfloorno as Floor,
    stuff( (SELECT ','+FL.nvrflatname
     FROM tbl_flatmaster FL 
     WHERE FL.intfloorid=F.intfloorid
     ORDER BY FL.nvrflatname
     FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 2, '') as FlatList
WHERE intblockid=1 
ORDER BY intfloorno DESC
```

will give

```
Floor   FlatList
1       FlatA1,FlatA2
2       FlatB1,FlatB2
```

not in seperate columns, but maybe what you want?

Answer (score 2):

OK, and if your original output contained 10000 instances of flats on floorno 1, you would want 9,999 dummy columns?

Ignoring the sorting of floorno -- which is easy with an ORDER BY clause --  you are confusing the output of a query with the display format of the output.

Query for the data with SQL, then pass it to some other process in which you can format it in your presentation layer.   If you describe what your presentation layer is (html?) then you can move your post to an HTML/XHR question about displaying the results of a request in a table.

Comment: This was my original thought, though it strikes me that he may just be looking to transpose a table

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to control presentational output? If so, this is the wrong approach. However, if you are trying to transpose your table, you may look into a [crosstab or pivot query](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-create-a-cross-tab-or-pivot-query.html).
Here's [another description](http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/91895.aspx)